# adding 1 to datetime filed in expression

Tags: informatica

I have a scenario of date/time field(invc_end_dt) I need to do a Trunc on the field and add 1 day to it. 
Example: 
if invc_end_dt has a date of 23:59:59 assuming it as Wednesday then I need to add 1 and make it to Thursday.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ADD_TO_DATE** function to achieve this. Please find below the syntax.

```
ADD_TO_DATE(invc_end_dt, 'D', 1 )
```

It is not required to do a Trunc beforehand to add one day. If your requirement is to ignore the time part you can do that trunc even after the addition.